# Show that : if $X$ is integrable then : $\lim_{c\rightarrow\infty}\mathbb{P}(\{|X|>c\})=0 $

Tags: probability, integration, measure-theory

Let $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\mathbb{P})$ be a probability space and 
$$
X: \Omega \rightarrow \mathbb{R}
$$ 
is a real-valued random variable.

Show that : if $X$ is integrable then :
$$
\lim_{c\rightarrow\infty}\mathbb{P}(\{|X|>c\})=0
$$

Comment: I mean... Sudheesh is, of course right, but if $X$ is on-the-nose $\mathbb{R}$ valued, you don't even need the assumption that $X$ is integrable for the statement to be true.

Answer (score 3):

This is a direct consequence of Markov's inequality,
$\mathbb{P}(|X|>c) \leq \frac{\textbf{E}(|X|)}{c}$. Taking limit as $c$ tends to infinity on both both sides gives the result.